# What is SOAP Services ? How can we integrate SOAP in IOS?

Tags: ios

What is proper Definition of SOAP?
Why To use SOAP?
How i can used SOAP in My iOS application?
what are Syntax Rules for soap?
Please give  me example of soap with iOS?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SOAP`, originally defined as `Simple Object Access Protocol`, 
`It is a protocol specification for exchanging structured information in` `the implementation of Web Services in computer networks.`

for more Info do Google.

"How can we integrate `SOAP` in `iOS`"

`Answer` : http://www.priyaontech.com/2012/10/soap-based-webservices-integration-in-an-ios-app/